# How to output in Sumatra without error?

Tags: errors, texstudio, sumatrapdf

I've now changed my command for external pdf viewer to be

`"C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"`

and similarly changed "the command line to be invoked when I double click the pdf document" in sumatra pdf to

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l`

Now, after I've done these changes, when I compile my latex file, it shows **Process exited with error(s)** on texstudio and **Error loading (pathname)** in sumatra pdf reader, when the pdf reader is already open. TeXstudio doesn't show error when sumatra pdf reader is not already open. The output is as expected everytime.

Please suggest some remedy.

**EDIT**
I've just realized that this error occurs whenever the default pdf viewer is not the internal one. Does this has a remedy?

Comment: Check out [https://www.ayazar.com/nb/kb/215-2-19969727-texstudio-sumatrapdf-search-link/](https://www.ayazar.com/nb/kb/215-2-19969727-texstudio-sumatrapdf-search-link/)

Comment: Or even better: [https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Use-Sumatra-as-a-pre-viewer-for-LaTeX-editors.html](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Use-Sumatra-as-a-pre-viewer-for-LaTeX-editors.html)

Comment: @gernot, the changes that I've done (mentioned in my question) are already taken from the first site you have linked. The second website says the same thing. The error persists when the default pdf reader is taken to be SumatraPDF reader.

Answer (score -1):

After about a year of attempts, I've finally solved it!

Go to Menu->Options->Configure TeXStudio->Build, then for your default pdf-viewer, click on the icon immediately in front of PDF viewer (hovering over which shows "Configure"). Then in "Ordered list of commands" on the right, add "Forward Search" and remove everything else.